# For a real valued function $g(t)$, how to prove that $G^{*}(f) = G(-f)$ , where $G(f)$ is the fourier transform of $g(t)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose real function g(t) has corresponding fourier transform G(f). In one text book I saw that the complex conjugate of G(f) equals G(-f). How to prove this?

ie for a real valued function $g(t)$, how to prove that $G^{*}(f) = G(-f)$, where $G(f)$ is the fourier transform of $g(t)$.

Any help or links to online references will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is straightfoward to prove from the definition of the Fourier transform:
\begin{align}
G^*(f)
  &= \int \overline{g(t) e^{-2\pi i f t}} \; dt \\
  &= \int \overline{g(t)} e^{2\pi i f t} \; dt \\
  &= \int g(t) e^{-2\pi i (-f) t} \; dt \\
  &= G(-f).
\end{align}
Note that proving the [basic properties of the Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform) and convolution boils down to manipulating integrals (usually a subtitution or Fubini's theorem does the trick).